# How to set property 'x-message-ttl' for queue in java

Tags: properties, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

How to set 'x-message-ttl' properties to this queue?

```
rabbit:
            bindings:
              TEST_RESPONSE:
                consumer:
                  bindingRoutingKey: "'${routing}'"
                  prefetch: ${prefetch}
                  acknowledge-mode: MANUAL
          bindings:
            TEST_RESPONSE:
              destination: TEST_RESPONSE
              content-type: application/json
              group: test
```

because a have this error

```
Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=406, reply-text=PRECONDITION_FAILED - inequivalent arg 'x-message-ttl' for queue 'TEST_RESPONSE.test' in vhost '/': received none but current is the value '60000' of type 'long', class-id=50, method-id=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to add a `spring-cloud-stream` tag. Doesn't look like this is RabbitMQ or even Spring AMQP issue. Since you have a queue already declared a passive declaration from Rabbit Binder should be disabled somehow...

Comment: that is not all application.yml, because it's too big, i just wanna know how declare quene with this property 'x-message-ttl'?

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queue definitions are immutable; you can't change a queue argument.

You either need to disable queue declaration

```
...rabbit.bindings.foo.consumer.bindQueue: false
```

or add

```
...rabbit.bindings.foo.consumer.ttl: 60000
```

to match the existing definition.

See consumer properties.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_rabbitmq_consumer_properties

Comment: Thanks a lot, that what i looking for